# Sort ListView data with ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I just want to sort my data by using sort and compare two value.

Here is my code:

```
        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myData);

        arrayAdapter.sort(myData, new Comparator<myData>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(myData o1, myData o2) {
                return Integer.compare(o1.getFinalScore(), o2.getFinalScore());
            }
        });

        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        dataList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

But I got the error said sort(java.util.Comparator) in ArrayAdapter cannot be applied to (java.lang.string[], anonymousjava.util.Comparator)

Can anyone tell what is the problem??

myData class

```
public class myData {

public int getFinalScore() {
    return finalScore;
}

public void setFinalScore(int finalScore) {
    this.finalScore = finalScore;
}

private String customeName;
private String carName;
private String appointmentDate;
private String email;
private String issueDescribe;
private String timeForJob;
private String costForJob;
private String reliableOnCar;
private String distanceJob;
private int finalScore;

public myData(String customeName, String carName, String appointmentDate, String email, String issueDescribe, String timeForJob, String costForJob,
              String reliableOnCar, String distanceJob, int finalScore) {
    this.customeName = customeName;
    this.carName = carName;
    this.appointmentDate = appointmentDate;
    this.email = email;
    this.issueDescribe = issueDescribe;
    this.timeForJob = timeForJob;
    this.costForJob = costForJob;
    this.reliableOnCar = reliableOnCar;
    this.distanceJob = distanceJob;
    this.finalScore = finalScore;
}
```

}

Comment: Well, the `compare` method takes Integer as parameter, not String, and your `o1.getFinalScore()` somehow seems to be of the `String` type.

Comment: It looks like you're using `myData` as a data type, even though `myData` is actually a variable name for the list. i.e. shouldn't `new Comparator<myData>` instead be `new Comparator<Integer>` ? The same goes for `compare(myData o1, myData o2)`

Comment: Can you post the code of `myData` ?

Comment: @Maxouille basically myData just the constructor and get/set, nothing else

Comment: And what's the type of the object returned by `getFinalScore()` ?

Comment: @Maxouille will be int

Comment: Post the code of myData anyway please

Comment: @Maxouille updated

Comment: rename your `ArrayList` to something other than `myData`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [sort()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#sort%28java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20T%3E%29) documentation for an ArrayAdapter, you can see that it takes only one argument, a comparator.

So you have to update your code like this :

```
arrayAdapter.sort(new Comparator<myData>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(myData o1, myData o2) {
                return Integer.compare(o1.getFinalScore(), o2.getFinalScore());
            }
        });
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Error gone, but the list still not sort

Comment: I think you should sort your list and not the adapter and then notify the adapter that the data have changed. But still, after sorting your `arrayAdapter`, you have to call `arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` to tell the adapter that data changed.